# M2mqtt Subscribing to topic using string variable

Tags: c#, arrays, string, uwp, mqtt

```
client.Subscribe(new string[] { "hello/world" }, new byte[] {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

I was testing the above and it works pretty fine.
But... When I try the below, my code doesn't works at all and don't throw any exceptions.

```
string variable = "hello/world";
client.Subscribe(new string[] { variable }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

**I've already tried:**

```
string variable = "hello/world";
string[] stringArray = new string[] { variable };
client.Subscribe(stringArray, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

Also:

```
 string variable = "hello/world";
 client.Subscribe(new []{ variable }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

How can I put it to work properly?

Thanks!

@edit:
Server-side logs:

```
Server auth 2b6240f1-593a-4217-b3d5-ae8c666099ca from 127.0.0.1    
Client 2b6240f1-593a-4217-b3d5-ae8c666099ca connected
Total connections: 3
$SYS/LIZO1uD/new/clients 2b6240f1-593a-4217-b3d5-ae8c666099ca
```

When a client connects and subscribes:

```
Server auth 6ba2d202-f595-4e37-a1d4-8ae6b134a370 from 127.0.0.1
Client 6ba2d202-f595-4e37-a1d4-8ae6b134a370 connected
Total connections: 3
$SYS/LIZO1uD/new/clients 6ba2d202-f595-4e37-a1d4-8ae6b134a370
$SYS/LIZO1uD/new/subscribes {"clientId":"6ba2d202-f595-4e37-a1d4-8ae6b134a370","topic":"hello/world"}
```

Comment: the first version"string variable = "hello/world";
client.Subscribe(new string[] { variable }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });"  should have worked. Maybe no messages arrived to the topic?

Comment: Yeah, it really should work. Actualy, i did not sent any test message. *But*, in the mosca server I can see if the client had any subscription, and the client only connects. Also, the rest of the code stuck too.

Comment: Updated the OP with the server-side logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a quick working example. Try and see if you get any result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

namespace MqttApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string BrokerAdress = "mqtt.server.local";
            string ClientID = "CSharpMqttClient";
            string Topic = "hello/world";
            string MessageToPublish;
            //Create MQTT client instance

            MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(BrokerAdress);
            Console.WriteLine("mqttClient instaceed for broker " + BrokerAdress);

            // register to message received 
            mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

            //Subscribe to the indicated topic
            // subscribe to the topic with QoS 2 

            mqttClient.Subscribe(new string[] {Topic}, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

            //Connect mqttCient

            mqttClient.Connect(ClientID,"","",true,60);

            Console.WriteLine(ClientID + " connected");
            // publish messages on "hello world" topic with QoS 2 

            MessageToPublish = "hello world";
            mqttClient.Publish(Topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MessageToPublish), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Published message: " + MessageToPublish);

          }

        static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            // handle message received 
            var msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Message Received: " + msg);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Man, thanks for your help. I've figured out the mess I was doing lol

Comment: if the above helped, maybe you can accept the answer and explained what changes you did to your code so other can do the same

Comment: It made me realize that I was initializing the string variable out of the mqtt scope. All I did to fix was puting the Mqtt stuff after the variable initialization. All fine now